# get the filename (image in phone storage /download folder)

Tags: java, android

downloaded image shows uri shown below
`dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/22`

while a get filename ==>22 is shown as filename which gives exception error 
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/22: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

but i need the exact filename which is img.dcm

```
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String path = uri.getPath() ;

        File fpath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS  ) ;
        String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        Log.d(TAG, "filename-----"+filename);
        Log.d(TAG, "path-----"+path);
        //File f = new File("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/0BF4-3218:dicom/2.dcm");
        File f = new File(fpath,filename);
        String dicomFile =   fpath +"/"+ filename ; //"D:\\JavaProjects\\Sample Images\\MR-MONO2-16-head";
        Log.d(TAG, "dicomFile-----"+dicomFile);
```

Comment: Why do you need the file name/path, specifically?

Comment: For security reasons, you will not get the path to the file. You can however achieve whatever you want with content resolvers.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver

Comment: @MikeM. i need file name to display in the imageview of android studio

Comment: @Rafsanjani could you please explain with an example

Comment: As stated by @MikeM, I don't see any use case where you will need the filename/path. If you want to display the image in an imageView, the best way will be to use an image loading library (glide or picasso) because they have very good caching strategies. Also you can just pass the uri to glide or picasso and the content will be automatically resolved for you.

Comment: @Rafsanjani I need to load a dicom image to imageview for that i am using pixelmed library .i get the correct path if copying image to download folder and it appends to imageview.but if the image is downloaded the path showing is  dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/22 so get exception file not found since filename is 22

Comment: Oops, my apologies. I didn't notice the extension on your filename. `BitmapFactory` won't help you with DICOM images. However, unless your library can accept an `InputStream` instead of a file path, you may have to use `openInputStream()` to copy the file to your app's internal storage, where you will be able to access it directly as a file, especially on newer Android version, as they are locking down file system access. Alternatively, if you can download the file directly to your app's internal storage, you won't have to do the copy, but I'm not sure how you're getting those files.

Comment: Rafsanjani and Mike Thanku so much for your reply

Answer (score 1):

You can get file name using this method

```
public String getName(String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int index = filename.lastIndexOf('/');
    return filename.substring(index + 1);
}
```

In this message pass your URI as an argument

```
getName(uri.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get image like this:

```
 private void pickImage() {
      Intent pickPhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      pickPhotoIntent.setType("image/*");
      startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pickPhotoIntent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_ONLY);
 }
```

You can get like this in onActivityResult() method:

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_ONLY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Uri selectedMediaUri = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedMediaUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Log.e("Image Path", "Image " + " " + picturePath);
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

For DICOM Images, here i am using imbrea SDK https://github.com/binarno/Imebra-V5-Android-Simple-Dicom-Viewer

```
public void loadDicomFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent()
                .setType("*/*")
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a DICOM file"), PICK_DICOM);
}
```

OnActivtyResult method for DICOM Images:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == PICK_DICOM && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                CodecFactory.setMaximumImageSize(8000, 8000);
                // Get the selected URI, then open an input stream
                if (data.getData()== null) {
                    return;
                }
                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

                // The usage of the Pipe allows to use also files on Google Drive or other providers
                PipeStream imebraPipe = new PipeStream(32000);

                // Launch a separate thread that read from the InputStream and pushes the data
                // to the Pipe.
                Thread pushThread = new Thread(new PushToImebraPipe(imebraPipe, stream));
                pushThread.start();

                // The CodecFactory will read from the Pipe which is feed by the thread launched
                // before. We could just pass a file name to it but this would limit what we
                // can read to only local files
                DataSet loadDataSet = CodecFactory.load(new StreamReader(imebraPipe.getStreamInput()));

                // Get the first frame from the dataset (after the proper modality transforms
                // have been applied).
                Image dicomImage = loadDataSet.getImageApplyModalityTransform(0);

                // Use a DrawBitmap to build a stream of bytes that can be handled by the
                // Android Bitmap class.
                TransformsChain chain = new TransformsChain();
                DrawBitmap drawBitmap = new DrawBitmap(chain);
                Memory memory = drawBitmap.getBitmap(dicomImage, drawBitmapType_t.drawBitmapRGBA, 4);

                // Build the Android Bitmap from the raw bytes returned by DrawBitmap.
                Bitmap renderBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dicomImage.getWidth(), (int) dicomImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                byte[] memoryByte = new byte[(int) memory.size()];
                memory.data(memoryByte);
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(memoryByte);
                renderBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(byteBuffer);

                // Update the image
                binding.ivMain.setImageBitmap(renderBitmap);
                binding.ivMain.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                android.app.AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dlgAlert.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Error");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //dismiss the dialog
                    }
                });
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                dlgAlert.create().show();
                String test = "Test";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: D/MainActivity: filePathColumn-----[Ljava.lang.String;@76e6a58                                       
 D/MainActivity: selectedMediaUri---content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/22
 D/MainActivity: columnIndex-----0
 D/MainActivity: picturePath-----null                  ,code not working

Comment: You can check my edited answer and it's working fine.

Comment: public void chooseImage() {
    
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);


    }

Comment: not working since i need to load DICOM IMAGE on imageview

Comment: You have set directly URI to imageview like imageView.setImageURI(imgUri) and can you please try full above code?

Comment: i have tried the above code ,selected a downloaded image from gmail in download folder of phone getting Log.e("Image Path", "Image " + " " + picturePath); as null

Comment: the image downloded was dicom and i need the same image to append on imageView of android studio

Comment: when i has downloaded image in gmail, it has also give me image path of download folder

Comment: Image Path: Image  /storage/emulated/0/Download/IMG-20191119-WA0001.jpg

Comment: this a JPG IMAGE I NEED DICOM IMAGE

Comment: i have to explore it

Comment: when i will found that, i will inform you

Comment: there is one aar file and Sample already given. please check it and follow the steps. Steps are already mentioned.

Comment: File fpath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());     ,how to get current clicked file name from fpath

Comment: sorry ,i coudn't find aar file , could you please explain where it is?

Comment: You can find it from above link

Comment: You can get current clicked item in OnActivityResult() method. In this data, you can get URI and from URI you can find path which is already implemented in above code

Comment: https://github.com/binarno/Imebra-V5-Android-Simple-Dicom-Viewer This is working code, i have checked it and you can find whole code from it.